Is it haram to accept birthday money or gifts if my parents are very insistent
okay so a bit of context my mom and dad are divorced and my dad is in Africa my parents have been divorced since I was around 3 my mom took us with her to America and their getting back together and their both in Africa right now and they won’t be back until after my birthday and my dad really excited because it’s going to be his first time giv8ng me a birthday gift and my mom said she’ll send me a 100 dollars and I tried telling my dad that I don’t want anything but he’s insistent and if I tell him it’s because I think it’s haram his going to say I’m overthinking it and if I say I don’t want anything he’s going to think that I’m mad their not going to be here for my birthday and my moms going to do the same and I have a hard time telling them no

There's a difference of opinion of if celebrating birthdays is haram or not, but even if you folllow the opinion that it is haram, you can receive the gifts nonetheless. Accepting gifts is, in fact, encouraged by the sunnah of the Prophet PBUH.

No it is not Haram, simply accept it ... giving gifts is encouraged, and you should show your appreciation in the best way that you can, as Allah says:

هَلْ جَزَاءُ الْإِحْسَانِ إِلَّا الْإِحْسَانُ
Is there any Reward for Good - other than Good?

and we are told in (Shia) Hadeeth from Imam Ridha PBUH that مَنْ لَمْ یَشْکُرِ الْمُنْعِمَ مِنَ الْمَخْلُوقِینَ لَمْ یَشْکُرِ اللَّهَ عَزَّ وَ جَل‏, which is translated into whoever does not thank the benefactor among the creatures has not thanked Allah Almighty, as according to Imam Sadiq PBUH, Allah AWJ does everything He wills through His creatures: ‍أَبَى اَللَّهُ أَنْ يُجْرِيَ اَلْأَشْيَاءَ إِلاَّ بِأَسْبَابٍ (link) which is translated into God refuses to cause things to happen except through means, and regular parents are among the ways Allah send people His mercy, like gives life to the babies through their mothers, or give foods and goods (رزق) usually through their fathers, and mothers are also among where Allah's Cherishing (الربّانیة) and Entirely Mercifulness (الرّحمانیة) and Especially Mercifulness (الرّحیمیة) are manifested. Therefore, simply accept the gift, and thank them, showing them how much happy you are.
